# The number 0 is contained in a confidence interval obtained by using bootstrap. Is the value of the parameter significant?

Tags: r, correlation, bootstrap

I have the following two ordinal variables:

```
x=c(29 ,19 ,31 ,48 ,11 ,33 ,23 ,16 ,19 ,9 ,24 ,5 ,22 ,10 ,26 ,18 ,16 ,26 ,10 ,25 ,16 ,17 ,18 ,21 ,19 ,11 ,11 ,9 ,73 ,37 ,25 ,11 ,16 ,19 ,15 ,16 ,26 ,21 ,17)

y=c(3 ,2 ,1 ,3 ,2 ,2 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,2 ,2 ,2 ,2 ,2 ,1 ,2 ,2 ,2 ,3 ,1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,2 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,2 ,1)
```

When I calculate the correlation between the two previous vectors:

```
cor.test(x,y,method = "spearman")
```

The result is:

```
Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  x and y
S = 6665, p-value = 0,04324
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0,3254013
```

In the previous result p-value <0.05; however when I apply the bootstrap:

```
dat = data.frame(x,y)
set.seed(1)

statistic1 = function(data, i) {
    cor(data[i, "x"], data[i, "y"], method='spearman')
  }

b3 <- boot(dat,statistic1,R = 1000)
b3
boot.ci(b3, type = c("perc", "bca"))
```

The result is:

```
Intervals : 
Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   (-0,0178,  0,6246 )   (-0,0547,  0,6109 )
```

The result applying bootstrap gives me a ci that contains the number 0. If the zero is included within the ci does it mean that the value of the correlation (0.325) is not significant?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer to your question is that, as Mark White discusses, p-values and confidence intervals are related, so you can say that some test that inverts your confidence interval fails to reject the value being nonzero. However, why are you running multiple tests of the same null hypothesis, particularly without adjusting for multiple tests? You might want to decide beforehand which test you will use, not [look at the results and pick the one that is most palatable.](https://xkcd.com/882/)

Comment: It should also be noted that the correlation coefficient is normalized to $|\rho|\leq 1$, and an absolute value less than one third is generally cosidered only a weak correltion, regardless whether the difference to zero is "significant" or not.

Comment: @Dave Although I believe that you are misjudging me when you pose "look at the results and pick the one that is most palatable" I accept your suggestion and that of Mark White.

Comment: @Dave My interest, at all times, is to know the truth, I do not obtain any benefit or profit with either of the two results. I am not a statistician, but I am very interested in this subject. I have always supported my research with the results of Inferential and / or Bayesian Statistics.

Comment: @Dave I just thought that all the tests would give the same result because I think that the truth is unique. In any case, in the case of this particular variable, I will take into account other aspects related to my profession that allow me to take a decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In frequentist statistics, confidence intervals and p-values are directly related to one another. If your null hypothesis that the correlation is zero, and your 95% confidence interval includes zero, then you indeed fail to reject the null hypothesis with an alpha set at .05.

The `cor.test` is using a test statistic with a closed-form solution, while the bootstrap is using a computational method to get a confidence interval. I unfortunately don't know much about how `cor.test` is calculating the p-value for the Spearman rank correlation—so I can't tell you which method to trust more. My gut says go with the bootstrap, but I may very well be wrong.

It looks like you've unfortunately got something right on the line of "being significant," so while different methods generally agree, they may provide slightly different answers. And sometimes that means one can cross the significance threshold and others don't.

This is a good example of researcher degrees of freedom (one may be tempted to report the one that is significant), and it also demonstrates how the significance level we set at .05 is arbitrary.

Comment: Is there any other method to find the correlation between these two variables to help me decide if there is a significant correlation or not?

Comment: @nilrem Pick a method and go with it, but that should be the method you would have picked before you saw the results (so you can’t just pick the one you want to be right). If you thought bootstrap was the way to go, ignore the cot.test output. This is no different than if a t-test and a Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney U test gave different results for a test of mean equality. (But why did you run both tests!?)

Comment: I did the two tests because I assumed that they should give the same result; in fact with the rest of the variables the results have coincided. Also I wanted to test the bootstrap. Anyway the truth is supposed to be unique no matter what proof I use. Please I would appreciate if someone could suggest some other method to help me decide.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the bootstrap often underestimates the width of confidence intervals, though. For hypothesis testing, you're generally better off performing a permutation test.

Comment: Reasonable people can disagree on if it's OK to run it multiple ways. I'm a fan of transparency and replication. To me, it's fine to do it multiple ways, just report that it's an iffy finding. And "an ounce of replication is better than a ton of inferential statistics" anyways!